# How to write a callback function in VB.NET called from C++

Tags: c++, vb.net

I am working with a DLL written in C++ provided by an external source with documentation but no source code.

I need to instantiate a callback function in VB.NET that is to be called by the C++ module in certain cases. The documentation provided looks like;

Function I call to establish the call back;

```cpp
extern "C" int EDIT_API Do_RunStuff( 
const int MyID, 
const char* my_tag1, 
const char* my_tag2, 
const char* some_data,
const int some_options,
int* some_count,
void* owner,
void* callback_func);
```

The template for the call back function is;

```cpp
typedef void (*CallbackRunStuff)( void* ptr2object, const char* my_tag1, 
const char* my_name, const char* some_code, 
const char* error_type, const char* message );
```

So I created my VB.NET code;

Declare the function;

```vb
Declare Function  Do_RunStuff Lib "SOME.DLL" (ByVal MyID As Integer, _
                                              ByVal my_tag1 As String, _
                                              ByVal my_tag2 As String, _
                                              ByVal some_data As String, _
                                              ByVal some_options As Integer, _
                                              ByRef some_count As Integer, _
                                              ByRef owner As IntPtr, _
                                              ByRef callback_func As IntPtr) As Integer
```

Call the function;

```vb
Dim objEditsErrorHandler As New editsErrorHandlerDelegate(AddressOf editsErrorHandler)
Dim objThis As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(Me)
Dim ptrEditsErrorHandler As IntPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(objEditsErrorHandler)
Dim ptrThis As IntPtr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(objThis)
intResult = Do_RunStuff(_AnID, strTag1, strTag2, strSomeData, someValue, SomeCount, ptrThis, ptrEditsErrorHandler)
```

Create delegate;

```vb
Public Delegate Sub editsErrorHandlerDelegate(ByRef objThis As IntPtr, ByVal strEditTag As String, ByVal strEditName As String, ByVal strAdminCode As String, ByVal strErrorType As String, ByVal strMessage As String)
```

Create Function;

```vb
Public Sub editsErrorHandler(ByRef objThis As IntPtr, ByVal strEditTag As String, ByVal strEditName As String, ByVal strAdminCode As String, ByVal strErrorType As String, ByVal strMessage As String)
    Debug.Print("*****====================*****")
    Debug.Print("Error Type: " & strErrorType)
    Debug.Print("Message: " & strMessage)
End Sub
```

Everything works swimmingly, when no callback is needed. When it attempts to do a call back to `editsErrorHandler` the program aborts with;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in

I do not know where to go from here. The DLL's developer is a C++ person and does not have an answer.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT 1**

In the documentation they show how to call from C++

Call to module that may do call back;

```cpp
FMyEngineClass->Do_RunStuff(my_tag1, my_tag2, some_data,
    some_options, &some_count, this, ShowErrorMessages);
```

Definition of function that is called back;

```cpp
static void ShowErrorMessages(void* caller, const char* my_tag1,
    const char* some_name, const char* some_code,
    const char* error_type, const char* message)
```

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you can use the debugger to see where in the C++ DLL the issue is triggered.   Either you or your C++ developer should have this already set up, if not, it is the time to do so,   Second, there is no mention of the calling convention you used for that VB function.  For C++, the calling convention, when not specified is `_cdecl`, and not `stdcall`  Mismatched calling conventions lead to these types of errors.

Comment: While I can talk with the C++ developer, we do not work together. The developer's initial reaction is that people have called it from C# and Java with no problem, what is my problem? I am running the VB.NET from the VS2012 IDE. but it displays nothing other than what I showed, on the line that calls the initial C++ routine.

Comment: Java uses the JNI or other wrapper to call the DLL functions without having to create delegates.  Thus have the developer or other person show you how it was done in C# (Java is not going to help you one bit).  Second, you can still run the program under the debugger and look at the call stack when the exception is thrown.  Last, look at how VB utilizes Windows API functions such as [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  How would you successfully set up a callback if you were to call that function?

Comment: Just to add, Java does not set the callback.  The callback is still set via C++ (or C) code, as if Java is not involved at all.  So you being told that "Java has no problems" was not helpful to you.

Comment: I have been given some C# code, but I believe it is incomplete and is using an additional layer of abstraction. So until I can get to the C# person to explain how he did it, I am somewhat blind. The c++ portion of the call stack is nothing but DLL name followed by 8 hex characters followed by "()"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I assume you are C++ developer. I am not. The use of this call back is to send messages back to a calling program. One idea is to write a Wrapper module in C++ whose only job is to receive a call from VB.NET, call the existing C++ module, receive the call backs, which would build a structure (actually an array of structures), that could then be passed back to the VB.NET calling program when the original C++ module returns control back to the wrapper. A) is this a viable Idea? B) Is this something that an experienced programmer (but no C++) could do without too much difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone else finds this, my particular problem was one silly line;

```vb
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
```

That needs to go immediately before;

```vb
Public Delegate Sub editsErrorHandlerDelegate(ByRef objThis As IntPtr, ByVal strEditTag As String, ByVal strEditName As String, ByVal strAdminCode As String, ByVal strErrorType As String, ByVal strMessage As String)
```

like so;

```vb
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Delegate Sub editsErrorHandlerDelegate(ByRef objThis As IntPtr, ByVal strEditTag As String, ByVal strEditName As String, ByVal strAdminCode As String, ByVal strErrorType As String, ByVal strMessage As String)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly use `GCHandle` to pass function pointers, and I seriously doubt you got the API declaration right (you seem to be getting away with it because you don't seem to use the parameters you got wrong).

I believe the following is correct:

```vb
<UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Delegate Sub editsErrorHandlerDelegate(ByVal objThis As IntPtr, <[In]()> ByVal strEditTag As String, <[In]()> ByVal strEditName As String, <[In]()> ByVal strAdminCode As String, <[In]()> ByVal strErrorType As String, <[In]()> ByVal strMessage As String)

Declare Function Do_RunStuff Lib "SOME.DLL" (ByVal MyID As Integer, _
                                             ByVal my_tag1 As String, _
                                             ByVal my_tag2 As String, _
                                             ByVal some_data As String, _
                                             ByVal some_options As Integer, _
                                             ByRef some_count As Integer, _
                                             ByVal owner As WhateverClassThisResidesIn, _
                                             ByVal callback_func As editsErrorHandlerDelegate) As Integer


Public Sub editsErrorHandler(ByVal objThis As IntPtr, ByVal strEditTag As String, ByVal strEditName As String, ByVal strAdminCode As String, ByVal strErrorType As String, ByVal strMessage As String)
    Debug.Print("*****====================*****")
    Debug.Print("Error Type: " & strErrorType)
    Debug.Print("Message: " & strMessage)
End Sub
```

```vb
Do_RunStuff(_AnID, strTag1, strTag2, strSomeData, someValue, someCount, Me, AddressOf editsErrorHandler)
```

If `WhateverClassThisResidesIn` is a structure, that will need to be `ByRef owner As ThatStructure`.